# Can I temporarily disable global $post?

Tags: loop

I have a PHP file `example.php` that prints out a list item linking to a the global post:

```
 <li>
     <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
 </li>
```

This file can be included with a Wordpress loop, like this:

```
 <?php
 while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
     $query->the_post();
     require("example.php"); // file from previous example
 }
```

I would like to print out a [HTML5 `<template>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) using this file, with all the HTML elements from `example.php` printed out, but not "filled in". To be clear, this is the result that I want:

```
 <template>
     <li>
          <a href=""></a>
     </li>
 </template>
```

To do that, I need to disable the global `$post` variable, maybe like this:

```
 <?php

 global $post;
 $post = null;
 ?>
 <template>
      <?php require("example.php"); ?>
 </template>
```

Is this correct? How do I reset the `$post` global to what it was before afterwards?

Comment: Technically you can assign $post to any other variable temporarily $my_var = $post, and then assign it back to itself later... $post = $my_var but I would not disable global $post at anytime anywhere. What are you trying to accomplish exactly because I am confused as to why you would load a file without content and then somehow add the content later?

Comment: @gdaniel I want the `<template>` element to use in Javascript, in a similar manner explained by this article: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/